# Hover image effect - what to add?

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I've been trying to achieve this effect to my site, but it seems that the code isn't working.
Here's the [sample site](http://sociallysorted.com.au/blog/).

And here's [the site I'm working on](http://bad-ass-miracles.com/blog/).

I'm mainly changing this part of the theme..

```
.main-content-area img.wp-post-image {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.main-content .wp-post-image {
}

.main-content-area img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Changing the min-width and height would reflect the changes, I'm not sure how to do it when hovering the image. Any advice would help. Thanks!

Comment: google "css hover", eg ."`main-content-area img:hover {your css for hover event goes here}`",. Having said that it's probable a jquery solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the CSS Transform Scale, paired with CSS Transition (which makes the css changes happen over a set interval of time).  Not my Fiddle, but here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/1206/

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Feel free to ask me anything else if you have any questions about it.

Comment: It still didn't work. At what part of the CSS element should I modify so it'll target image for the hover effect?